# Solving a linear system in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_{12}$. I need to solve the following system in $\mathbb{Z}_{12, +, \cdot}$ for every $\alpha$ : \begin{cases} 6x + 5y = 0 \\ 8x + y = \alpha \end{cases} I'm confused because I'm not sure if the same is meant with \begin{cases} 6x + 5y \equiv 0 \mod 12 \\ 8x + y \equiv \alpha \mod 12 \end{cases} Are these systems equivalent? And how do I go on about solving the first one? Should I set up an augmented matrix and row reduce like for normal systems?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent. The difficulty comes from the fact that $\mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z$ is a ring with zero-divisors, and the determinant of the system is precisely a zero-divisor.

Comment: Multiply the first equation by $2$. Then $12x+10y=0$, hence $10y=0$.

Comment: So this means $y = 0$. Then I should solve $8x \equiv \alpha \mod 12$ ?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$8x+y\equiv\alpha\pmod{12}\iff5(8x+y)\equiv5\alpha$$

$$5(8x)-6x\equiv5\alpha\pmod{12}\iff5\alpha\equiv-2x$$

So, $\alpha$ must be even to admit any solution.

$\alpha=2\beta$(say)

$$\implies2x\equiv-10\beta\pmod{12}\iff x\equiv-5\beta\pmod6$$

Comment: I don't understand why $5\alpha \equiv -2x$ ? How does that follow from the previous step?

Comment: @Kamil, As $$5(8)-6=34\equiv-2\pmod{12}$$